# Generate unique list item id for all list items in site collection

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need mechanism simillar to Document ID the only difference is I would like to use it for custom list. What is the best approach to generate unique id for all list items in SharePoint site collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a list named *Unique IDs* and programmatically (or via workflow) add items to it. Then you could use IDs (built-in field named *ID*) of these items as unique IDs (the first item ID is always 1). This way you will have a sequential unique ID. The list can be located in the root web so the sequence can be unique per site collection. Additionally you could prepend the ID with some prefix to distinguish sequences of every site collection.

Comment: I thought about similar solution but I'm afraid about concurrency issue. How to avoid it?

Comment: There is no concurrrency issue. The ID field is primary key auto-generated by SharePoint and thus is guaranteed to be unique (per list instance of course).

Answer (score 0):

There is no comparable feature to the documentID service for Items in general out of the box.  You would have to build it using Custom code. You can create a custom ID which appends the list GUID and the OOTB item ID which is unique to every item in the site collection.

Comment: I know there is no OOTB solution. I want to generate good looking IDs not GUIDS. Something like global ID generator. It would be fine if it creates ID only for lists with specific content type. I just don't know how it could be done. Any Ideas?